# dynamically assigning values to properties depends on another list

Tags: c#, .net

I will try to explain with an example the scenario. Lets assume that i have a below tables called person and mycolumns.
table person holds a column which holds the json object.

```
table mycolumns definition like below
{
id int identity(1,1),
columnName varchar(50),
PersonId int
}
```

this table holds custom columns for a person using his Id and those values will be stored in person table as json object. (these configured columns are fixed to 5 and with names)

Now when i store person i can store what ever the json i need into json column. but when i get i have to make sure i will only populate a custom model with only the custom columns and their values which are derived for this person through MyColumns table.

Person cumtom model will holds all those 5 columns as properties but only have to populate values for those which are having an entry in mycolumns table for that person.

so far i tried a plain way of doing it by getting the columns from mycolumns table for that person.

```
mycolumns = getcolumns(personId);
if(mycolumns.contains("mycolumn1"))
personModel.mycolumn1 = GetFromJson("MyColumn1").Value;
if(mycolumns.contains("mycolumn2"))
personModel.mycolumn2 = GetFromJson("MyColumn2").Value;
.....
```

Is there another way of doing this in an efficient way.. I am working on using reflection but still trail ans error.

Comment: Not sure I understand fully.  But could you not decode the custom part as a dictionary?

Comment: yes i do, but for example am storing {"myColumn4": "100", "myColumn5": "Writer"}  and in mycolumns table for this person "myColumn5" is mapped then my custom model should populate only "myColumn5" value as "Writer". i have to popuate all other custom properties in customModel as null. (Even though "myColumn4" is in json but not configured to person)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var myColumns = GetColumns(personId);
var modelType = personModel.GetType();
foreach (var column in myColumns)
{
    modelType.GetProperty(column)?.SetValue(personModel, GetFromJson(column).Value);
}
```